# Review of Database Design

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a user authorization database. Haven't much work with ACLs before. Trying to keep things somewhat simple. I guess my question would be. Am I missing anything?

**Purpose:**

The database is to allow access to applications and any granular authorization with in those applications.

**Theory of Operation**

Users belong to Groups. 
Applications Belong to Groups.
Authorization is based on Group/Role.

You would have to fill in the sysAplicationList, sysApplicationAclList, and sysAclRoles tables. Create your groups, assign the applications to the groups. Then filling in the sysGroupApplicationAclList At this point the role would be assigned. Then sysGroupApplicationRoleItems would list the ACL item for that group, application, role

**Diagram**

[image]

**Tables**

sysAplicationList - Holds the list of applications installed on the system.
sysApplicationAclList - Repository of possible to ACLs for the application.
sysAclRoles - Roles in the system.

sysGroupDetailList - Name of groups.
sysApplicationGroupMemebership - Applications in a group.
sysGroupApplicationAclList -
sysGroupApplicationRoleItems - ACL items per AclList.

sysUsersDetailList - User information.
sysUserGroupsMemebership - User assigned groups.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest - databases already implement security through the use of ROLEs and PRIVILEGEs - why are you rolling your own security scheme?

Comment: Of course as soon as I posted this RBAC and ABAC started showing up in may searches. I'm coming in a lot more blind than I thought I was. Any suggestions what to use?